# Migrating web site from local PC to Windows 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5)

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, iis-7.5, migration

The company I work for is interested in moving a local Intranet web site I made for them from my test box to one of their servers. My testbox is running Windows 7 64x, and the server is running Windows 2008 R2. The web site is written in PHP and MySQL, and I have the needed modules and extensions available. However, I was curious about a few things. Namely, whether or not I need any 'special' kind of extension or module to run PHP and MySQL. Secondly, I can't seem to find any solid instructions on migrating from a local PC to a Windows server (both the PC and the server are running IIS 7.5). I know I'm going to have to rewrite a good portion of my code, due to the fact that it uses Windows authentication, but hopefully this will be easier on the server.

The main thing I'm asking here is just if you have any tips or suggestions on how to do this, things I shouldn't miss, etc. I'm confident that if I tackle this then I can get it, but I'm hoping to minimize the potential damage. Also, I use WAMP server for the MySQL storage on my computer / the testbox. Will I be able to use phpMyAdmin on the R2 server as well, or do I need a different approach, and if so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using IIS locally as well? There's literally no difference. There is however a major difference if you're going Apache -> IIS as you'd need to install PHP on your server.

Comment: A side note, The windows authentification is the same, you can still continue to use your own built-in authentification mechanism if you want too. Not because it's a server you need to use it

Comment: You will be able to user MySQL-phpMyAdmin in Windows server 2008 R2 with (IIS 7.5). To get good control over php extensions, you may install php manager for IIS through Microsoft Web Platform Installer (Handy tool for Windows based server). Here is a good guide you can follow to deploy a local website in Remote IIS web server.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32210/Deployment-of-a-Website-on-IIS